# callback in scipy.optimize does not call first value

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, callback, scipy-optimize-minimize

I've got this simple Problem with callbacks in scipy.

I'm using optimize.minimize with values (func, x0, callback=callbackFunc).
The callback function does work, BUT only returns the values after step 1.

```
x0=(240.,220.)
Nfeval=0
interim_res
optimize.minimize(func, x0, callback=callbackFunc)
def callbackFunc(X):
    global Nfeval, interim_res
    print('{0:4d}   {1: 3.6f}   {2: 3.6f}'.format(Nfeval, X[0], X[1]))
    Nfeval += 1
    interim_res.append([X[0], X[1]])
```

So in my opinion it should start with

```
0    240    220
...
```

BUT first return is:

```
0    173.345    159.56
```

Is this the usual way minimize works or do I somehow interpret something wrong?

Comment: Could you show us function func,the ones you want to find optimal minimum?

Comment: @MishaVacic You could use any functions, for example rosen or the sphere function, it happens in every case

Answer (score 4):

The [minimize documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html) says for callback (emphasis mine):

> Called **after** each iteration, as callback(xk), where xk is the current parameter vector.

Hence, it should just be the way minimize works, that must be the result after the first iteration, not the value it starts with. If you want to be fully sure that it starts with the value you want, you can always print the argument that is passed from *minimize* to *func* on each call.